# Hottest and coldest points on a plate given by $T =2x^2−3y^2−2x+10$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, maxima-minima

I am asking this question because my professor tells me my procedure is not enough to prove my answer. I disagree. That being said, consider the following:

The temperature of a rectangular plate bounded by the lines $$x = ±1,y = ±1$$ is given by $$T =2x^2−3y^2−2x+10$$ Find the hottest and coldest points of the plate.

My solution was very simple:
$$t_x=4x-2=0$$$$\Rightarrow x=\frac12$$

$$t_y=-6y=0$$$$\Rightarrow y=0$$
Now, since $t_{xx}>0, x=\frac12$ is a minimum, and $t_{yy}<0, y=0$ is a maximum. Therefore, $P_1(\frac12,0)$ will not be a maximum nor a minimum. Hence, I only had to check the correct combinations. In other words, for example, since $x=\frac12$ is a minimum $y$ has to be as large as possible if we want to find the minimum. Likewise, at  $y=0$, $x$ has to be as large as possible to maximize the temperature. Intuitively, these points have to occur at the boundary (because of the shape of the graph of $T$). Therefore, $P_2(\frac12,±1)$ is the coldest point, and
$P_3(-1,0)$ is the hottest.

My question is, is my procedure enough to prove those points are the hottest and coldest, in other words, is it true in general for quadratic equations?

I know this graph has no saddle points because it lacks $xy$ term.

Comment: Are you sure the graph even passes through the rectangular plate? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @BrianBlumberg, may I ask you one thing? I am not a college student and I am looking forward to have a career in ML. So once I join college, is this question you posted here one sort of questions that I'll see while learning math as a part of studying for ML??

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is yes. @Spectre

Comment: @BrianBlumberg thanks then... :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh... I see you indeed found *all* solutions:

[image]

So you look fine to me.  Find all inflection points and then either test them explicitly, or compute second-order derivatives in both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, is it correct in general?